# How can I show overlay on top of the whole app in flutter?

Tags: flutter, overlay

I want to show an overlay on the whole app so I tried to insert an overlay entry on the context of MaterialApp (root widget) but the problem is I'm getting the null value on invoking the following method :

```
Overlay.of(context);
```

```
GetMaterialApp.router(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
          scaffoldMessengerKey: Keys.scaffold,
          scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
          routeInformationParser: WebRoutes.goRouter.routeInformationParser,
          routerDelegate: WebRoutes.goRouter.routerDelegate,
          routeInformationProvider: WebRoutes.goRouter.routeInformationProvider,
          builder: (context, child) {

          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
              addOverlay(context);
            });
           
            return child;

}

void addOverlay(BuildContext context) {
  print(Overlay.of(context));

  return Overlay.of(context)?.insert(OverlayEntry(
    builder: (context) {
      return SomeWidget();
    },
  ));
}
```

Is there any way to get the state of overlay using the context of this root widget as I want to show the overlay globally.

Thanks alot, I really appreciate that If someone helps me.

Comment: What is the error you encountered?

Comment: I got null value, I don't get overlay on the context I passed.

Comment: Overlay.of(context) this method returns null.

Comment: I think you are calling the overlay with the context which doesn't have Material aap. I cannot tell you exactly, please share the exact error/exception you encounter after calling the overlay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: getIt.get<NavigatorService>().navigatorKey,
        theme: AppTheme.defaultTheme,
        initialRoute: AppRoutes.splashScreen,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Stack(
              children: [
                child!,
                Positioned(
                  top: 15,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 50,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: const Center(child: Text("HI I AM AN OVERLAY")),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        onGenerateRoute: AppRoutes.onGenerateRoute,
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Peter for your answer, I appreciate it from the bottom of my heart, but I used that approach before and It worked for me, the issue I faced was debugging, when enabling the overlay guidelines from the dev tools, I also saw the blurry screen.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by create a class responsible to display/remove the overlay, this class need receive a `BuildContext` when creating to be able to create an instance of `Overlay`.

Basically what you need to do are:

1. Create a class `OverlayScreen` that build the `OverlayState` && `OverlayEntry` (in this case the `OverylayEntry` will be a list of OverlayEntry since we might have more than one Overlay on the screen so we can remove all of them at once).
2. Create an instance of this class earlier in your app (e.g MyApp). In your case you'll need to call this inside Material.router...builder param.
3. Access this `overlayScreen` in your HomePage to display|removeAll overlays

Lets create our OverlayScreen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OverlayScreen {
  /// Create an Overlay on the screen
  /// Declared [overlayEntrys] as List<OverlayEntry> because we might have
  /// more than one Overlay on the screen, so we keep it on a list and remove all at once
  BuildContext _context;
  OverlayState? overlayState;
  List<OverlayEntry>? overlayEntrys;

  void closeAll() {
    for (final overlay in overlayEntrys ?? <OverlayEntry>[]) {
      overlay.remove();
    }
    overlayEntrys?.clear();
  }

  void show() {
    overlayEntrys?.add(
      OverlayEntry(
        builder: (context) {
          return _buildOverlayWidget();
        },
      ),
    );

    overlayState?.insert(overlayEntrys!.last);
  }

  OverlayScreen._create(this._context) {
    overlayState = Overlay.of(_context);
    overlayEntrys = [];
  }

  factory OverlayScreen.of(BuildContext context) {
    return OverlayScreen._create(context);
  }

  Widget _buildOverlayWidget() {
    return Positioned(
      top: 20,
      left: 20,
      right: 20,
      child: Container(
        width: 300,
        color: Colors.black,
        height: 300,
        child: const Text("MY CHAT"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now lets create an instance on `MyApp`

```
// Need to have it global to be able to access everywhere
OverlayScreen? overlayScreen;

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const HomePage(),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Overlay(
          initialEntries: [
            OverlayEntry(
              builder: (context) {
// Create an instance of `OverlayScreen` to be accessed globally
                overlayScreen = OverlayScreen.of(context);
                return child ?? const SizedBox();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

To finalise lets create our `HomePage` and access our `overlayScreen` there there

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:overlay_all_app/src/overlay_screen.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Create an instance of OverlayScreen
    final overlayScreen = OverlayScreen.of(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // display the overlay
                overlayScreen.show();
              },
              child: const Text('Display Overlay'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Call your next screen here
              },
              child: const Text('Go to next page'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // removed all overlays on the screen
                overlayScreen.closeAll();
              },
              child: const Text('Close Overlay'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That's it. You can use this class OverlayScreen to show/removeAll wherever you want.

I created a PR with sample code, check it out https://github.com/antonio-nicolau/flutter-working-with-overlay

[image: Global Overlay]

Comment: Thank you so much, bro, It worked for me, but I wanted to use the MaterialApp overlay context as I read in docs that MaterialApp creates Navigator and Navigator creates Overlay. BTW I used your approach in my project so again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(App2());
}

class App2 extends StatelessWidget {
  App2({super.key});
  final _router = GoRouter(
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (context, state) => const OverlayWrapper(),
      ),
    ],
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp.router(
      routeInformationParser: _router.routeInformationParser,
      routerDelegate: _router.routerDelegate,
      routeInformationProvider: _router.routeInformationProvider,
    );
  }
}

class OverlayWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  const OverlayWrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OverlayWrapper> createState() => _OverlayWrapperState();
}

class _OverlayWrapperState extends State<OverlayWrapper> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  showOverLay() {
    OverlayEntry overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: const Text('data'),
      ),
    );
    Overlay.of(context).insert(overlayEntry);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showOverLay();
          },
          child: const Text(
            'ShowOverlay',
            style: TextStyle(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer seems to be incorrect given that the question was about how to add an
Overlay using .router Navigator 2.0. The best way to do this is to wrap the navigator widget in an overlay in the build method of the RouterDelegate like this:

```
class AppRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<AppRoute> with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin<AppRoute> {
  

  final PageNotifier notifier;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final SideMenu _sidMenu = const SideMenu();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey;

  AppRouterDelegate({required this.notifier}) : _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  
  @override
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> get navigatorKey => _navigatorKey;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


   //THIS EXAMPLE SHOWS USING A SCAFFOLD IN THE OVERLAY WITH A SIDE MENU AND BUTTON


   return Overlay(
              initialEntries: [
                    OverlayEntry(
                      builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                        key: _scaffoldKey,
                        drawer:  _sidMenu,  //UTILIZE THE DRAWER PROPERTY FOR A SIDE MENU 
                        body: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Navigator(
                                key: navigatorKey,
                                pages: [
                                  //YOUR PAGE LOGIC
                                ]
                            ),
                            Positioned( // ADD AN ICON TO OPEN SIDE MENU
                              top: 10.0, 
                              left: 10.0,
                              child: IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.menu, size: 30.0),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
              );

     
  } 

  //Rest of your router delegate code

}
```